# How to create attributes dynamically in python?

Tags: python

I have a class like this:

```
class User:
    def __init__(self, uid):
        userinfo = json.load(urlopen(passportapi + 'user/' + uid))
```

This class would load user information from a remote api and set corresponding attributes for this class so I can access these attributes by:

```
print user.username
print user.group_id
```

Is there any way to implement this?
Thanks

Comment: Which part are you having trouble with?

Comment: I have no idea how to write the code for this class to allow me access it's attributes like 'print user.username'

Comment: How about this? `print vars(user)['username']` You can replace 'username' with the name of any attribute you want to access

Comment: I believe Smashery's answer is more suitable for my problem :-) Just need to write his code in __init__(self) and everything works well. :-)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
import json

api_result = '{"username":"wawa","age":20}'

class User(object):
    def __init__(self, api_result):
        userinfo = json.loads(api_result)
        self.__dict__.update(userinfo)

import unittest

class DefaultTestCase(unittest.TestCase):
    def test_default(self):
        user = User(api_result)
        self.assertEqual(user.username, 'wawa')
        self.assertEqual(user.age, 20)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

Comment: This is the most complete answer :-) Thank you.

Answer (score 7):

You can do this sort of thing using the `setattr` function:

```
>>> class A(object):
    pass
>>> a = A()
>>> setattr(a, 'val', 4)
>>> a.val
4
```

In your case, assuming your parsed json file provides some sort of key-value pair (like a dict), you can just iterate through those, and call `setattr` on `self`; something like this (assuming `userinfo` is a dict):

```
class User:
    def __init__(self, uid):
        userinfo = json.load(urlopen(passportapi + 'user/' + uid))
        for key, value in userinfo.iteritems():
            setattr(self, key, value)
```

Answer (score 2):

Assuming your JSON request returns a Python dictionary:

```
class User:
    def __init__(self, uid):
        self.__dict__.update(json.load(urlopen(passportapi + 'user/' + uid)))
```

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes I like to have a little more encapsulation and control than what 'update' would offer.  I would probably accomplish what you are trying to do like this:

```
class User(object):                                                             
    def __init__(self, api_result):                                             
        self.userinfo = json.loads(api_result)                                  

    def __getattr__(self, name):                                                
        if name in self.userinfo: return self.userinfo[name]                    
        raise AttributeError
```

I think this method will allow you to do other things like filter certain keywords and raise custom exceptions for accessing your data.